# Overflow hidden not allowing me space on the right

Tags: html, css

I have overflow-x hidden in order to remove the white space on the right side of the page on mobile view.
This is making so I cannot add any margin to the right of the page as well.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-1,
.post-2,
.post-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

//Media queries
.post-1,
.post-2,
.post-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-container">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="main-post-pic">
        <a href="recentpost.html" target="_blank"><img class="latest-post-img" src="pics/study- 
                 work.jpg" alt="study-work"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="latest-post">
        <h2> Working and Studying Full - Time - What the heck?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="www.google.com"><button class="read-more">Read more about this</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-container">
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="main-posts-container">
      <div class="post-1">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/overwhelmed.jpg" alt="study-work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-1">
          <h2> Feeling Overwhelmed?</h2>
          <div id="date">19/04/2020 - 3 min read</div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post-2">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/wake-up.jpg" alt="study- 
                    work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-2">
          <div id="date">19/04/2020</div>
          <h2> Waking up 5am in the morning!</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post-3">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/growth.jpg" alt="study- 
                    work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-3">
          <div id="date">19/04/2020</div>
          <h2>Growth mindset: is it real?</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to have the same margin I have on the "post" section. Basically make it so my main posts are centered and with some white space between them and the page margin.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for? I just removed the margin-left you have given to the post-1 to post-3 and add width: 60%; and margin: 2px auto; to centralize them. you can change width and margin-top and margin-bottom as you like.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-1,
.post-2,
.post-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 2px auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

//Media queries
.post-1,
.post-2,
.post-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-container">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="main-post-pic">
        <a href="recentpost.html" target="_blank"><img class="latest-post-img" src="pics/study- 
                 work.jpg" alt="study-work"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="latest-post">
        <h2> Working and Studying Full - Time - What the heck?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="www.google.com"><button class="read-more">Read more about this</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-container">
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="main-posts-container">
      <div class="post-1">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/overwhelmed.jpg" alt="study-work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-1">
          <h2> Feeling Overwhelmed?</h2>
          <div id="date">19/04/2020 - 3 min read</div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post-2">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/wake-up.jpg" alt="study- 
                    work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-2">
          <div id="date">19/04/2020</div>
          <h2> Waking up 5am in the morning!</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post-3">
        <a href="../html-link.html"><img class="blog-pic" src="pics/growth.jpg" alt="study- 
                    work"></a>
        <div class="post-intro-3">
          <div id="date">19/04/2020</div>
          <h2>Growth mindset: is it real?</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, perferendis tempora inventore voluptatem unde ratione aut veritatis adipisci distinctio, maiores, quae ullam nobis laboriosam alias facere ipsa esse totam vitae.</p>
          <p class="more">Read more about this ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```